# Regex com retorno condicional em Java

Tags: java, regex

Estou com problema para validação de uma expressão regex, onde eu tenho uma string da seguinte forma:

```
PESO50GM/23KG/14LB
```

Preciso verificar no regex se consta informação com KG, ja retorna a informação com KG, senão retorna GM senão LB, então deve seguir esta ordem:
Eu fiz desta forma, porém ele esta pegando sempre a primeira informação com GM, ex:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "([0-9]{1,8}KG)|([0-9]{1,8}LB)|([0-9]{1,8}GM)";
        final String string = "PESO50GM/23KG/14LB";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
               
    }
}
```

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Se entendi, fiz `([0-9]{1,8}KG)|([0-9]{1,8}LB)|([0-9]{1,8}GM)` Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Comment: A resposta do @DanielIkenaga está correta e funciona bem, porém atente-se a ordem dos grupos, eles Serão determinantes para obter a ordem de precedência desejada, na resposta do Daniel a ordem dos retrovisores ficariam 1 - KG, 2 - LB e 3 GM, então bastaria inverter os grupos 2 e 3 da regex apresentada pelo Daniel

Comment: Sem informar qual a engine de expressões regulares fica difícil o oferecer a melhor solução pois cada implementação possui particularidades. Algumas engines oferecem padrões de captura condicional bastante elaborados, outras implementações oferecem padrões de captura condicional mais simplificados e ainda há implementações que não permitem padrões de captura condicional sendo nessas possível ou não emular padrão de captura condicional com backtracking. Também informa mais detalhes sobre a composição da string a ser analisada.

Comment: Desculpa pelas informações erradas, e formatação errada, primeira vez que publico, acabei até respondendo, sendo que nao precisava. Sim é em java e usando dessa forma como foi comentado abaixo: String regex = "([0-9]{1,8}KG)|([0-9]{1,8}LB)|([0-9]{1,8}GM)", String string = "PESO50GM/23KG/14LB";, ele ainda acaba retornando grupos, e nao somente o valor que eu quero, como se fosse por prioridades. Vou remover minha resposta abaixo.

Comment: E qual é o valor que vc quer afinal? Vc diz que sempre retorna o GM, mas é porque a string tem GM, ué. O que era para retornar? Se tiver KG é pra ignorar o GM? Tem exemplos de string que não tem KG e/ou LB?

Comment: Exato, dentro da string tem as 3 informações, GM, KG e LB, mas se tivesse uma forma de dentro da regex eu trazer por prioridades, se dentro da mesma string ter as 3 informações, pegar o KG primeiro e ignorar as demais, caso nao tivesse o KG, e dentro da string tivesse o GM e LB, pegar o GM e ignorar o LB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até existe [regex condicional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), mas o Java não suporta (e mesmo se suportasse, eu não usaria, porque acho desnecessariamente complicado para a esmagadora maioria dos casos, incluindo este).

O problema do `Matcher` é que ele sempre buscará todos os trechos que satisfazem a regex. E no caso, você sempre busca pelas 3 unidades, por isso sempre vai achar todas que existirem.

Um jeito de resolver é buscar todos os trechos existentes, e depois verificar quais existem, de acordo com sua prioridade:

```java
String regex = "[0-9]{1,8}(KG|LB|GM)";
String string = "PESO50GM/23KG/14LB";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
String[] unidades = {"KG", "LB", "GM"};
String[] pesos = new String[unidades.length];
while (matcher.find()) {
    String dados = matcher.group(); // para cada match, verifico qual unidade ele contém
    for (int i = 0; i < unidades.length; i++) {
        if (unidades[i].equals(matcher.group(1))) {
            pesos[i] = dados;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for (String s : pesos) {
    if (s != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        break;
    }
}
```

Ou seja, tenho um array `unidades` com a ordem de preferência (primeiro "KG", depois "LB", e depois "GM").

Eu guardo todos os *matches* encontrados em um array `pesos`, na mesma ordem de prioridade do array `unidades`. Se alguma unidade não existir (por exemplo, se a string não tiver "KG"), a posição correspondente em `pesos` será `null`. Depois, é só percorrer o array `pesos` até encontrar o primeiro elemento que não seja `null`.

Veja também que simplifiquei a regex (e aproveitei para deixar a unidade em um grupo separado, assim fica mais fácil comparar com os elementos do array `unidades`).

---

Outra alternativa é tentar uma unidade de cada vez, até encontrar:

```java
String string = "PESO50GM/23KG/14LB";
String regex = "[0-9]{1,8}";
String[] unidades = {"KG", "LB", "GM"};
for (String unidade: unidades) {
    // tenta cada unidade, uma a uma
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex + unidade);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
        break; // se encontrou, encerra o loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Certo, entendi... melhor fazer a verificação em todos, vou tentar aplicar